# Using output of previous commands in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In Mathematica, it is possible to reuse the output of the previous command by using %.

Is something similar possible for bash (or some other shell)?

For example, I run a make which gives warnings, but I want to find all warnings.
So, I type

```
make | grep "warning"
```

but I'm not able to see the output of the make then.

I would like to type something like this instead:

```
make
% | grep "warning"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the amount of output is indeterminate, it doesn't make sense for `bash` to store it for you for re-display. But there's an alternate solution to your problem:

The `tee` command allows you to duplicate an output stream to a file. So if you're willing to use a file for temporary storage, you can do something like this:

```
make | tee output.txt
grep "warning" output.txt
```

This solution avoids running `make` twice, which could be (a) expensive and (b) inconsistent: the second make may be doing less work than the first because some targets were already made the first time around.

Note: I haven't tried this. You may need to fiddle with joining the error and output streams, or such.

Comment: Right. it actually doesn't make sense to store the entire output. The tee command seems useful though.

And I tried it. Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
make
!! | grep "warning"
```

By using `!!` you tell it to repeat the last command in that spot, along with any other bash commands you want to add to it.

The downside is that if the command you are repeating takes a long time to execute, you'll have that much longer to wait unless you stored the output of the previous command to an output file first.

Answer (score 3):

Swap the `stdout` and `stderr` streams to log the entire `stderr` stream:

```
make 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | tee /dev/stderr > stderr.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the `make` command sends warnings to stderr but I suspect it does. try this

```
make 2&>1 |grep 'warning'
```

it will redirect stderr to stdout.

Should also note that you can't grep anything that's not going to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

If you use tee to duplicate the output stream to /dev/stderr, there's no need for a temp file; plus, after that, you can filter the stdout stream with sed to create a make_warning.log file - all in one line of Unix shell pipes.

```
make 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr | \
   sed -E -n 's/(.*[Ww][Aa][Rr][Nn][Ii][Nn][Gg].*)/\1/p' > make_warning.log
```